# JSLT foreach transform in JSON array

Tags: json

Got an interesting problem. I have a JSON array that looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "date_open": "2021-09-09",
  "date_last_updated": "2021-09-21",
  "status": "open",
  "project_name": "Project:5",
  "office": [
    {
      "name": "office_one",
      "completed": true,
      "required": true,
      "contact_date": "2021-09-13",
      "response_date": "2021-09-15",
      "completion_date": "2021-09-15"
    },
    {
      "name": "office_two",
      "completed": true,
      "required": true,
      "contact_date": "2021-09-13",
      "response_date": "2021-09-21",
      "completion_date": "2021-09-21"
    },
    {
      "name": "office_three",
      "completed": false,
      "required": false,
      "contact_date": null,
      "response_date": null,
      "completion_date": null
    },
    {
      "name": "office_four",
      "completed": false,
      "required": true,
      "contact_date": "2021-08-23",
      "response_date": "2021-09-01",
      "completion_date": null
    }
  ]
}
```

I already have a JSLT expression that modifies the JSON to add a total days_open field at the top using some computation of the date_open field and the date_last_updated field.

```
let date_started = parse-time(.date_open, "yyyy-MM-dd")
let date_last_update = parse-time(.date_last_updated, "yyyy-MM-dd")
let days_open = ($date_last_update - $date_started) / 86400

{  
  "days_open" : $days_open,
  * : .
}
```

Pretty basic stuff, but it works and gives me a new field called days_open. What I need to also do is iterate through each office in the office array and do something similar. Basically, if `required` is `true`, compute the days between `contact_date` and `completion_date`. If `completion_date` is `null`, the compute the days between `contact_date` and `response_date`. If `response_date` is `null`, then compute the days between `contact_date` and `date_last_updated` in the parent object.

My final output needs to look like this:

```
{
  "id": "12345",
  "date_open": "2021-09-09",
  "date_last_updated": "2021-09-21",
  "days_open": 12,
  "status": "open",
  "project_name": "Project:5",
  "office": [
    {
      "name": "office_one",
      "completed": true,
      "required": true,
      "contact_date": "2021-09-13",
      "response_date": "2021-09-15",
      "completion_date": "2021-09-15",
      "duration": 2
    },
    {
      "name": "office_two",
      "completed": true,
      "required": true,
      "contact_date": "2021-09-13",
      "response_date": "2021-09-21",
      "completion_date": "2021-09-21".
      "duration": 8
    },
    {
      "name": "office_three",
      "completed": false,
      "required": false,
      "contact_date": null,
      "response_date": null,
      "completion_date": null,
      "duration": null
    },
    {
      "name": "office_four",
      "completed": false,
      "required": true,
      "contact_date": "2021-08-23",
      "response_date": "2021-09-01",
      "completion_date": null,
      "duration": 9
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm a complete JSLT n00b here. Is there a way to iterate through the JSON array? Do something like an `if then else` or a `foreach`?

Answer (score 0):

There were a couple of challenges to this one, but if you know JSLT well it's not hard. Here's a solution.

```
def days_between(date1, date2)
  let time_started = parse-time($date1, "yyyy-MM-dd")
  let time_ended = parse-time($date2, "yyyy-MM-dd")
  ($time_ended - $time_started) / 86400

let last_updated = .date_last_updated
{  
  "days_open" : days_between(.date_open, .date_last_updated),
  "office" : [for (.office) . | {
    "weird_days" : if (.required) 
      days_between(.contact_date, fallback(.completion_date, .response_date, $last_updated)),
    * : .
  }],
  * : .
}
```